# Google contacts sync error on HTC 8X WP8 GDR3

Tags: sync, contacts, gmail, google

I hard reset-ed my phone HTC 8X yesterday and added the contacts again and found out that it gives an error on the Google account!!

Here is the error message:

> Google error
>   Not updated 
>   Your phone doesn't have enough memory to sync information at the moment.
>   Last tried 12 minutes ago 
>   Error code: 800700E

The phone storage is empty as reset-ed it.

Can anyone help me with this? as all of my contacts are exists on Google.

**UPDATE 4:** the issue here with the contacts sync ONLY, the mail just works fine!

UPDATE:

OS version: 8.0.10501.127

[image]

UPDATE 3:
phone storage:

[image]

Comment: The only thing I can say is that I'm currently in GDR3 and I don't have this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the issue.

The issue was from the pictures associated with the contacts at Google so I removed all of the pictures then the sync worked perfect.

> The pictures may be too large for Windows Phone to handle.

Reference: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/winphone/forum/wp8-wpaccount/google-contacts-sync-error-on-htc-8x-wp8-gdr3/06d61a94-27de-43ec-b620-b856803b125c#ThreadAnswers